# Can not execute the makemessages command

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I want to use i18n, and I created a locale directory, and other settings in my `settings.py`.

Then I execute the `python manage.py makemessages -l zh-cn` command in my PyCharm, but failed.

My traceback is bellow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 296, in execute
    parser = CommandParser(None, usage="%(prog)s subcommand [options] [args]", add_help=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 51, in __init__
    super(CommandParser, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1597, in __init__
    self._positionals = add_group(_('positional arguments'))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 569, in gettext
    return dgettext(_current_domain, message)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 533, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 468, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 440, in find
    for nelang in _expand_lang(lang):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 133, in _expand_lang
    from locale import normalize
ImportError: cannot import name normalize
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is because in your `locale` directory there are `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc` files, you should delete them.

Right click the locale directory -> Reveal in Finder -> then you can see them, if you only shows it in the Pycharm, you can not see the `.pyc` file.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Probably the right answer, but care explaining why? It might not be so obvious to the OP.